# Check for statistical significance in this scientific work.

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I will have a few minutes to present a poster in a scientific meeting happening in some days.

I gathered some data regarding a particurar medical procedure and outcomes.

It's reported that outcomes vary proportionally with the age of the patient (the oldest have the worst prognosis).

I would like to check my database for statistical significance but a few hours of reseach brought me nowhere. Any hint is highly appreciated.
0=good outcome; 1= bad outcome.

```
AGE OUTCOME
80  0
32  1
21  1
69  0
62  0
76  0
74  0
56  0
78  0
58  1
45  0
50  1
36  0
63  0
86  0
53  0
60  0
69  0
71  0
90  1
76  0
76  0
80  1
81  0
75  0
78  0
77  0
56  1
44  0
20  1
77  0
45  0
59  0
19  0
82  1
42  1
62  0
```

Comment: did you try doing a contingency table $\chi^2$ test?

Comment: You can [make a table using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5044/290189).

Comment: @DavidQuinn Yes I tried, it gives me: Chi-squared test: 29,820 DF 27 Significance level P = 0,3223... I wanted to check for >75 yrs and < 75 yrs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check that the data is normally distributed in each of the outcome groups. A Normal Q-Q Plot of group $0$ indicates violation of normality

[image]

and a Shapiro-Wilk Test confirms that

```
> shapiro.test(df$AGE[df$OUTCOME==0])

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  df$AGE[df$OUTCOME == 0]
W = 0.89618, p-value = 0.01095
```

Since the data is not normally distributed, we will continue with a nonparametric test of our choice. The Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test seems like an appropriate choice.

Let

$$H_0:\mu_1 =\mu_2$$

$$H_a : \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$$

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  AGE by OUTCOME
W = 169, p-value = 0.2516
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

so we do not have significant evidence that the group means differ.

In fact, the median age of outcome $1$ is lower than in group $2$ which contradicts your claim.

```
> median(data$AGE[data$OUTCOME==1])
[1] 53
> median(data$AGE[data$OUTCOME==0])
[1] 69
```

Comment: Impressive! Thanks a lot, really inspiring. So we cannot say younger get the good outcome neither the opposite right (they get the worst outcome significantly more than the older)?

Comment: Yes, it does not appear that you have significant evidence that either population mean is greater than the other